# Security tokens with unreadable private keys?

Tags: security, public-key-encryption

I'd like to uniquely identify users by issuing [security tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) to them. In order to guarantee [non-repudiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) I'd like to ensure that no one has access to the user's private key, not even the person who issues the tokens.

What's the cheapest/most-secure way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a 3rd party certificate authority: you don't know the private key and you don't have to care about how the client gets and secures the private key (but you can worry about it). Not the cheapest solution ever...

OR:

1. Share a secret with each client (printed on paper, through email, phone, whatever...).
2. Have the client generate the keys based on that secret, time (lets say 5 minute intervals) and whatever else you can get (computer hardware id - if you already know it, client IP, etc...). Make sure that you have the user input the secret and never store it in an app/browser.
3. Invalidate/expire the tokens often and negotiate new ones

This is only somewhat safe (just like any other solution)...if you want to be safe, make sure that the client computer is not compromised.

It depends on where/how you want to use those keys* but the bottom line is that in the case of asymmetric keys, the client will encrypt the data sent to you (the server) using their private key and you (the server) will decrypt that data using the client's public key (opposite of how HTTPS works).

Can you verify, at any point in time, the identity of your clients?

If the client computer is compromised, you can safely assume that the private key is compromised too. What's wrong with SSL/HTTPS. Do you really need to have one certificate per client?

Tokens are not the same thing as keys and they don't have to rely on public/private keys. Transport, however, might require encryption.

*my bank gave me a certificate (which only works in IE) used to access my online banking account. I had to go through several convoluted steps to generate and install that certificate  and it only works on one computer - do you think that your clients/users would agree to go through this kind of setup?

Comment: Only the user should be in possession of the private key. Using a certificate authority won't help because then **they** would know the user's private key. I need one certificate per user because I need [Personal Identity Verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_201) for my application.

Comment: @Gili The CA does not need to issue the private key; it signs the public key.  If you are issuing PIV-I cards, certificates *must* be signed by a trusted CA: §2.4.1 of the federal [interoperability guidance](http://www.idmanagement.gov/documents/PIV_IO_NonFed_Issuers_May2009.pdf) [PDF] indicates that "[Non-Federally Issued] PIV Cards must include an identity authentication PKI certificate issued by a CA that chains to the Federal Bridge Certification Authority (FBCA) [...]"

Comment: @drf, sorry, I didn't mean to imply that I am trying to adhere to the PIV standard. I just meant that I am trying to create a system that uniquely identifies individuals. I get your point about CAs though. So you're saying, let the user generate a private key and post their public key to a CA. This approach sounds risky. Wouldn't it be relatively easy for compromised computers to steal the user's private key?

Comment: @Gili - I needed some more space to respond more fully to your question, so I provided an answer as a separate response.  (This is not to detract from bkdc's response, which is completely accurate.)

Answer (score 1):

It would be relatively easy for compromised computers to steal the user's private key if it were stored as a soft public key (e.g., on the hard drive).  (APT (botnet) malware has been known to include functionality to do exactly this.)

But more fundamentally, nothing short of physically incapacitating the user will guarantee non-repudiation.  Non-repudiation is something the user chooses to do, opposing evidence notwithstanding, and to prove that a user *didn't* do something is impossible.  Ultimately, non-repudiation involves a legal (or at least a business) question: what level of confidence do you have that the user performed the action he is denying having performed and that his denial is dishonest?  Cryptosystems can only provide reasonable confidence of a user's involvement in an action; they cannot provide absolute proof.

PIV cards (and PIV-I cards) use a number of safeguards for signing certificates.  First, the private key is stored on the smart card, and there is no trivial way to extract it.  The card requires a numeric PIN to use the private signing key, and effectively destroys the key after a certain number of incorrect attempts.  The [hardware cryptomodule](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips201-1/FIPS-201-1-chng1.pdf) must meet Level-2 standards and be tamper-resistant, and transport of the card requires Level-3 physical security (FIPS 201).  The certificate is signed by a trusted CA.  The PIN, if entered using a keyboard, must be sent directly to the card to avoid keylogger-type attacks.

These precautions are elaborate, intensive, and still do not guarantee non-repudiation.  (What if malware convinces the user to sign a different document than the one he is intending to sign?  Or the user is under duress?  Or an intelligence agency obtains the card in transit and uses a secret vulnerability to extract the private key before replacing the card?)

Security is not generally a question of cheapest/most secure, but rather of risk assessment, mitigation, and ultimately acceptance.  What are your significant risks?  If you assess the types of non-repudiation risks you face and implement effective compensating controls, you will be more likely to find a cost-effective solution than if you seek to eliminate risk altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to handle non-repudiation in a digital signature app is to use a trusted third party, a 3rd party cert authority.

Be careful trying to create your own system--since you're not an expert in the field, you'll most probably end up either losing the non-repudiation ability that you seek or some other flaw.

The reason the standards for digital signatures exist is that this stuff is very hard to get right in a provable way. See "[Schneier's Law](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html)"

Also, eventually, non-repudiation comes down to someone being sued--you say that "B" did it (signed the agreement, pressed the button, etc), but "B" denies it. You say you can "prove" that B did it. But so what, you'll need to prove in court that B did it, to get the court to grant you relief (to order B to do something such as pay damages.)

But it will be very very expensive to sue someone and to prove their case due to a digital sig system. And if you went to all that trouble and then the digital sig system was some homebrew system, not a standard, then your odds of relief would drop down to about 0%.

Conclusion: if you care enough about the digital sig to sue people, then use a standard for digital sig. If you will ultimately negotiate rather than sue, then look at the different options.

For example, why not use a hardware [security token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) They're now available as apps for people's phones, too.

Comment: Smartphones penetration is only 20% in the US as of 2010. I am targeting the mass-market, in Canada no less, so this pretty kills that idea. What do you mean "be careful trying to create your own system"? Is there a reasonable existing system for non-repudiation of clients?

Comment: @Gili: Be careful because it is easy to get it wrong and hard to prove that you haven't gotten it wrong. Re: is there an existing system? Yes, see security tokens.

Comment: I don't think security tokens are enough for non-repudiation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signatures#Using_digital_signatures_only_with_trusted_applications -- As far as I can tell, it's impossible to prove that the operating system has not been compromised and unless you can do that, you can't prove you are signing what you are viewing.